# Proof about cyclic group with prime order and the relation between the cardinality of the set on which it acts and the fixed points of the set

Tags: group-theory

If $p$ is prime, and $C$ is the cyclic group of order $p$, and $\rho$ is the group action from $C$ to the symmetry group on a set $X$, then $|X| \sin|X^G| (\mod p).$

Where $X^G$ is the set of fixed points.

I tried fiddling with the theorem stating $|\mbox{Stab}X||\mbox{Orbit}X|=|G|$, but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: You need that different orbit partition the set i.e. $\# X=\sum_{i=1}^t \# \mbox{Orb}_{x_i}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X$ as the disjoint union
$$ X = \bigcup_{x\in T} \operatorname{Orb}(x),$$
where $T$ is a system of distinct representatives of the orbits of the action of $G$ on $X$.  Since, for each $x\in T$, we have $\left|\operatorname{Orb}(x)\right| = \left| G\right|/\left| G_x\right|$, the size of each orbits is a divisor of the order of $G$.  Since $G$ has order $p$, the only divisors are $1$ and $p$, so each orbit is either of size $p$ or $1$. The orbits of size $1$ are the fixed points. So, we get
$$\left| X\right| = \sum_{x\in T}\left|\operatorname{Orb}(x)\right|,$$
and each term on the right side of this equation is either $1$ or $p$.  Modulo $p$, those equal to $p$ disappear, and the remaining terms add up to the number of fixed points (modulo $p$).

Notice that the argument works if the order of $G$ is any power of $p$, not just $p$ itself, so this is true for any $p$-group.